# Why does ArrayList class uses the name elementData as attribute and as method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand that fact. ArrayList stores data in :

`private transient Object[] elementData;`

Now when for instance we add an element to the ArrayList, it uses the following :

```
public boolean add(E e) {
  ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
  elementData[size++] = e;
  return true;
}
```

I don't understand the line `elementData[size++] = e;` . And I saw a method I think this line is related to :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E elementData(int index) {
        return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

I don't understand why `elementData` is used both as a method name and an attirbute name...

Comment: Why not? There is not ambiguity and the purposes are very closely related.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please explain me. I don't understand why they wrote things like that. The first method seem to be adding space to the already created array `elementData` (which should not be possible since array size is immutable) and the function below seem to play a role in it. That's what I don't understand

Comment: What do you think `size` represents? Hint: it is not the length of `elementData`, which as you correctly state is fixed unless reallocated by `ensureCapacityInternal()`.  The _method_ `elementData(int)` plays no role in `add()`.

Comment: "And I saw a method I think this line is related to " the two aren't related, directly. One is storing data in the array; the other is retrieving data from the array.

Comment: @JimGarrison  Haaa thanks for clarifying it does not play a role in add.Since `add` uses `ensureCapacity` does it mean that `size` holds the before increase lenght of the array ?

Comment: The array has a fixed length. `size` is the current number of entries that are in use.  `size <= elementData.length` is an invariant.  After creation and before anything is added, `elementData.length` will be some positive value and `size` will be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the array is of type Object[], writing to it is type safe, hence the direct write access.

```
elementData[size++] = e;
```

Reading is different, because we need the elements to be of type `E`, not `Object`. We assume this is going to be valid (at least if clients behaved well), but we need to have one place where we make the cast and convince the compiler this is safe. That's where the `elementData(int)` method comes in, along with its `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Comment: I saw an answer about `@SuppressWarnings` so I understand the compiler issue. Now do you mean that `elementData[size++] = e;` implicitly calls the `elementData(int)` method ? If it does how is it even possible to change the size of the array (since array size is immutable)?

Comment: @Bloomberg58. It does not call the method. `elementData(...)` and `elementData[...]` are completely unambiguously referring to different things. The assignment is safe because the type of the array is wider.